# RegEx: Match additional characters (some of them non-English)

Tags: regex

I have this regex [`[0-9]\.\s*|\s?\([^)]*\)|\.`](https://regex101.com/r/rW9mN0/1) to match some characters as shown below. It works fine but I would like it to match additionally " - wkład do teorii poznania" as in an example below. This is too hard for me, especially because the example contains (and other matches may) non-English characters.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you try it the other way? exclude anything that is not a regular character.

Comment: Why the picture? Post a link to the regex101 sample and it's **so** much easier for us to help you ;)

Comment: I posted a link to regex 101 sample - just click the regex:)

Comment: (?![a-zA-Z]) see if this works

Comment: @MukundGandlur Could you provide me with full regex, please?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit weird to answer one's own question but I will do it anyway.

[`[0-9]\.\s*|\s?\([^)]*\)|\s-\s(.*)|\.`](https://regex101.com/r/rW9mN0/4) does the trick.

Comment: It's shouldn't be weird, as it's encouraged. The guidelines say you should accept your own answer if it's the best one (in your opinion).  It's all about creating the most complete online resource for others. You don't get any rep for accepting, but it does save others coming here trying to answer a (supposedly unanswered) question.

Answer (score 0):

[^a-zA-Z\n]. This is the complete regex. Hope this is what you need.

Here is the permalink https://regex101.com/r/rW9mN0/3.

Comment: It fails to do what it is supposed to do. I would like it to match additionally " - wkład do teorii poznania" - it won't match it. Additionally, it matches characters that it should have.